# Postgresql : null values cannot be formatted as an SQL identifier

Tags: postgresql

how to resolve this `ERROR: null values cannot be formatted as an SQL identifier` when trying to select my function:

```
select ws_sls_core.ars_pricing_test()
ERROR:  null values cannot be formatted as an SQL identifier
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "select string_agg(distinct format('(props ->> %L) as %I', w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_desc, w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_desc), ', ')
                       from ws_sls_core.w_support_pricing_d 
    left join ws_sls_core.w_order_line_d 
    on w_support_pricing_d.svc_pricing_type = w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_cd"
PL/pgSQL function ars_pricing_test() line 6 at SQL statement
```

I have checked and the query in use doesn't produce any NULL

```
select * from ws_sls_core.w_support_pricing_d where svc_pricing_type is
  null
```

I have tried the below-mentioned code without JOIN and it works fine, I need an additional column and have to use join, and I am only seeing this error.

Here is my complete code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ws_sls_core.ars_pricing_test(
    )
RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
declare
  l_sql text;
  l_columns text;
begin
    select string_agg(distinct format('(props ->> %L) as %I', w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_desc, w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_desc), ', ')
    into l_columns
    from ws_sls_core.w_support_pricing_d 
    left join ws_sls_core.w_order_line_d 
    on w_support_pricing_d.svc_pricing_type = w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_cd;
--     and A.svc_pricing_type is not null;
  
  l_sql := 
    'create or replace view ars_pricing_test as 
     select w_support_pricing_d.item_num, '||l_columns||' 
     from (
      select w_support_pricing_d.item_num, json_object_agg(w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_desc,w_support_pricing_d.mnth_maint_price) as props
       from ws_sls_core.w_support_pricing_d 
        left join ws_sls_core.w_order_line_d 
        on w_support_pricing_d.svc_pricing_type = w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_cd
       group by w_support_pricing_d.item_num 
     ) t';
  execute l_sql;
  return true;
end;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION ws_sls_core.ars_pricing_test()
```

Comment: Check again - either you or the database is wrong and the database is a lot more thorough than us weak fleshy humans. Also - if you can't have nulls why are you using a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: post the datatype for svc_pricing_type  from the table ws_sls_core.w_support_pricing_d , check distinct values of the column

Comment: `w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_desc` is the issue and that is coming from `...from ws_sls_core.w_support_pricing_d left join ws_sls_core.w_order_line_d...` so it is entirely possible it is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling hour for a very similar issue. Apparently seems that even you do not pass null values there must be something happening into SQL Optimizer which requires null check:

Try the following:

```
IF l_columns IS NOT NULL
THEN
    l_sql := 
        'create or replace view ars_pricing_test as 
         select w_support_pricing_d.item_num, '||l_columns||' 
         from (
          select w_support_pricing_d.item_num, json_object_agg(w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_desc,w_support_pricing_d.mnth_maint_price) as props
           from ws_sls_core.w_support_pricing_d 
            left join ws_sls_core.w_order_line_d 
            on w_support_pricing_d.svc_pricing_type = w_order_line_d.matl_grp2_cd
           group by w_support_pricing_d.item_num 
         ) t';
      execute l_sql;
      return true;
END IF;
```

The variable l_columns is used into formatter and therefore it should be a null check before passing to formatter.